# Disabling Autofill on <textarea> in Chrome

Tags: forms, google-chrome, textarea, autofill

Has anyone found a way to achieve this? I've tried adding `autocomplete="off"` on both my `<textarea>` and my `<form>` but to no avail. Google Chrome continues to suggest addresses for me on one of my textareas:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-4">Permanent Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only thing I can find online is how to stop Google from autofilling usernames / passwords, but nothing to do with `<textarea>` elements